# How are strings compared in IF statement arguments

Tags: c++

In the if function argument, how is the string s and t compared? Why is the condition (s > t) true?

```
string s = "to be";
string t = "not " + s;              // t = “not to be”
string u = s + " or " + t;          // u = “to be or not to be”
if (s > t)                          // true: “to be” > “not to be”
cout << u;                          // outputs “to be or not to be”
```

Answer (score 2):

[std::string operator comp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)

> All comparisons are done via the `compare()` member function (which
>   itself is defined in terms of Traits::compare()):
>
> - Two strings are equal if both the size of lhs and rhs are equal and each character in lhs has equivalent character in rhs at the same
>     position.
> - The ordering comparisons are done lexicographically -- the comparison is performed by a function equivalent to
>     std::lexicographical_compare or std::lexicographical_compare_three_way
>     (since C++20).

So, in short it does a [lexicographical compare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

I.e. `"to be"s > "not to be"s == true` because - at first position - `'t' > 'n'`.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison of `std::string` was designed to be not surprising, or at least minimally surprising. If you stick to lowercase letters and spaces, as in your example, `operator<` and `operator>` follow alphabetical ordering.

- `not to be`
- `to be`
- `to be or not to be`

Since you are sticking to the simple case, `string{"to be"} > string{"not to be"}` because they are in reverse alphabetical order. That is, `'t' > 'n'` (as characters).

When you expand into other characters, there might be some surprises. For example, `'Z' < 'a'` since ASCII puts capital letters before lowercase letters. Still, the principle still holds: the ordering of `std::string` is based on the ordering of the underlying character set. Look for the first character position where the strings differ; the strings are ordered the same as the characters in that position. If one (and only one) string ran out of characters before a difference was found, then the shorter string comes before the longer one.